# Convert Html files to png using perl WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: html, image, perl, firefox, mechanize

I am trying to convert HTML files to png files using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox in perl

the code i have used for it

```
        use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
        use Path::Class qw/file/;

        my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
          bufsize => 10_000_000, # PNGs might become huge
        );
        my $count=0;
        while($count<90){
        $count++;
        chomp($count);
        my $k="file:///C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/file/$count.html";
        print"$k\n";
        $mech->get($k);
        my $name="$count.png";
        my $fh = file( $name )->open( '> :raw' );
        print $fh $mech->content_as_png();
        $k='';
        }
```

The html files are named as 1.html, 2.html as follows.
so i have assigned $counter as a variable for the address.But, it getting terminated in the second iteration of while loop. i have some doubts in the get() function i used in here. Please give me some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Presuming the path is readable, your call to `get()` looks fine. Are you seeing any specific error message? Is it failing on any particular line?

Comment: @rutter Thank you, the error message is `Got Status code 500 at line 13`

Comment: Hmm. The underlying library isn't giving you very much to work with, in that error message. =\ Line 13 looks like the `get()` call, which makes me think you might be trying to access a path which doesn't exist or can't be read.

Comment: as far i see,No issues in the path